# How to Populate a ListPicker in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight without issues

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

this is my ListPicker on XAML :

```
<toolkit:ListPicker  x:Name="CursoLista" Header="Curso" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding Curso}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

And Cs File :

```
ObservableCollection<FgCurso> ObjCurso = new ObservableCollection<FgCurso>();
```

The FgCurso Class

```
class FgCurso
{
    public String Curso { get; set; }
}
```

And the instanciate of class

```
public void ListaCurso()
    {
        ObjCurso.Add(new FgCurso { Curso = "Administração" });
        ObjCurso.Add(new FgCurso { Curso = "CCO" });
    }

CursoLista.ItemsSource = ObjCurso;
```

And works fine, the problem is, when i put more than 5 itens inside of ListPicker it doesn't work,i got [image: this],

I don't know how to solve that issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `ListPicker` has more than 5 items, it will open in full screen mode. The `FullModeItemTemplate` also should be provided for the items to be displayed in correct format while in full mode.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="FullModeTemplate">
   <.../>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NormalTemplate">
   <.../>
</DataTemplate>

<ListPicker ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NormalTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource FullModeTemplate}" />
```

The `ItemTemplate` will be used when the `ListPicker` expands in the page and the `FullModeItemTemplate` will be used when it opens in full mode.

Comment: So, i don't need to change nothing inside of DataTemplate? thanks!